# php foreach multidimensional array getting information

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm having some troubles getting information from an array. I'm in need to get all information per key basis but I can't get it.

I have this array:

```
Array(
[en] => Array(
    [a] => Array(
        [0] => [C][C]
        [1] => [L][L][C]
    ) [b] => Array(
        [0] => Tackle
        [1] => RazorLeaf
    ) [c] => Array(
        [0] => 
        [1] =>
    ) [d] => Array(
        [0] => 20
        [1] => 50
    )
) [pt] => Array(
    [a] => Array(
        [0] => [C][C]
    ) [b] => Array(
        [0] => Pontapé
    ) [c] => Array(
        [0] =>
    ) [d] => Array(
        [0] => 20
    )
)
)
```

In a foreach (or multiple), I'm in need to get `[en][a][0]`, `[en][b][0]`, `[en][c][0]` and `[en][d][0]` to insert data into database.
In the next loop is supposed to get `[en][a][1]`, `[en][b][1]`, `[en][c][1]` and `[en][d][1]` .
Last but not least, after change from `[en]` to `[pt]` it should get `[pt][a][0]`, `[pt][b][0]`, `[pt][c][0]` and `[pt][d][0]`

My approach:

```
                        foreach($result as $language => $index){
                        foreach($index as $attinfo => $index2){
                            //echo "$language <br/> $attinfo <br/>";
                            foreach($index2 as $valorfinal => $index3){
                                echo $index[$attinfo][$valorfinal][$index3]."<br/>";
                            }
                        } 

                    }
```

My approach seems not to work as expected. Could someone guide me please?
I would like to save in vars each key to then save them in database in each foreach loop. Thanks.

Comment: user nested `foreach()` to get that

Comment: I have an answer to this problem on another question, and this answer works on ANY dimensional size array, "Iterate through every single key and value in a multi-dimensional associative array PHP" : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52508096/2430549

Comment: @HoldOffHunger your approach is interesting. Thanks for sharing that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've re-organised the loops and corrected the indexes used in the final data access (you are using `[$index3]` as an index when it's a value)...

```
foreach($result as $index){
    foreach($index['a'] as $key => $value){
        $data = [];
        foreach ( $index as $key1 => $value1)   {
            $data[] = $index[$key1][$key];
        }
        print_r($data);
    }
}
```

this outputs...

```
Array
(
    [0] => [C][C]
    [1] => Tackle
    [2] => 
    [3] => 20
)
Array
(
    [0] => [L][L][C]
    [1] => RazorLeaf
    [2] => 
    [3] => 50
)
Array
(
    [0] => [C][C]
    [1] => Pontapé
    [2] => 
    [3] => 20
)
```

To include the language in the output...

```
$output = [];
foreach($result as $language => $index){
    foreach($index['a'] as $key => $value){
        $data = [];
        foreach ( $index as $key1 => $value1)   {
            $data[] = $index[$key1][$key];
        }
        $data[] = $language;
        $output[] = $data;
    }
}

print_r($output);
```

Gives (partial output)...

```
Array
(
    [0] => [C][C]
    [1] => Tackle
    [2] => 
    [3] => 20
    [4] => en
)
```

Comment: your approach is right, but it confused me. So now I don't have the first key `[en]` or `[pt]` that is in array. I need that value to insert it in database too. Also, with your approach, with a foreach, how should I access all information one by one?

Comment: To get the first key, use `foreach($result as $language => $index){` and `$language` should be the `[en]` value.  Not sure about what you mean by *how should I access all information one by one*

Comment: I got that answer and before asking I achieved the same result , but I would like to have it as key too `[4]`. Instead of language before each pack of values,have it inside `[0][1][2][3][4]` - where the 4 would be the language. Is this possible?

Comment: I've updated the answer (last code segment) (changed language addition to `$data[] = $language;`)

Comment: It creates everything in the same "array" instead of creating as much instances as exists: ```Array(
 [0] => [C][C][1] => Tackle[2] => [3] => 20[4] => en[5] => [L][L][C][6] => RazorLeaf[7] => [8] => 50[9] => en[10] => [C][C][11] => Pontapé[12] => [13] => 20[14] => pt
)```

Comment: Are you sure you have the line `$data = [];` in the loop as in the example code?

Comment: With $data = []; in the loop it only returns the last array. Doesn't return all arrays since it's creating a new one.

Comment: Updated to create `$output` as all of the rows.